# Make non-editable text box but its value should be posted back to the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I want that a text box on my HTML form must not be editable, yet its value, which will be pre-filled when the HTML form is displayed, must be posted back to the Web server.

If I disable a textbox in my HTML, when I post back the form with its data, the value of the disabled textbox is not posted back.

How do I make the value of the disabled textbox also be posted back?

This is what I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Name))
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Disabled fields should still be getting posted back. Is this through an html form submit, or AJAX?. 

Without seeing any more code, you might consider putting what you need in a hidden field along with the disabled field

Comment: Disabled fields are not posted with form data by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

If you wish to have a textbox whose value the user cannot edit but the value in the textbox must be posted back to the server, apply the *readonly* attribute on it as such:

```
<input type = "text" redaonly" />
```

So, in an MVC view, here's what you do:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Name))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, 
      new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
}
else
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `readonly` attribute on your input and optionally gray it out with CSS.

```
input[readonly] {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```